# How do I turn this into a callback that triggers when a user changes the dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, html, function, callback

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and am trying to make my first program.

The program essentially presents users with a series of dropdown boxes, and their selections will all be collated at the end to form a joined text string. [My original JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanCUK89/hwfmekub/2/) shows the program working correctly for one dropdown box, and I'm now trying to rework it into a function so that this process can be repeated for several different dropdown boxes.

[My NEW JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanCUK89/k5ypdufa/2/) shows that I've now re-written my code as a function, and accept the two parameters (categoryOptions - the different arrays to populate the selection boxes with) and (selector - the actual selection in the HTML doc to target).

```
// Step 4 - Function which will print the selected value into the content HTML element
// Need helping turning this into a callback for the function above.
// I want this function to run but only when the select box is changed.
function printSelection() {
    var finalSelection = selector.value;
    console.log(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = finalSelection);
}

}

populateSelects (progressOptions, progressSelector);
```

I now want to print the value selected by the user to the page and assign it to 'finalSelection'. Unfortunately it says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: selector is not defined"' but I'm not sure how to pass it the value that they have selected.

I understand I need to do this as a callback, that takes place 'on change' but am not sure how to do this with the main populateSelects function.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function and on **onchange** of select you can call the function passing **this** as an argument.
**this** points to the html element calling the function.
You can try below snippet. Also I have modified **populateSelects** a bit to be able to create all dropdowns in single call.

```js
// Step 1 - Store Strings to be passed to categoryOptions Parameter
let progressOptions = ["Just testing!", "XX has made excellent progress", "XX has made good progress", "XX has made poor progress"];
// Behaviour Options
let behaviourOptions = ["XX has excellent behaviour", "XX has good behaviour", "XX has poor behaviour"];
// Attendance Options
let attendanceOptions = ["XX has excellent attendance", "XX has good attendance", "XX has poor attendance"];
// Punctuality Options
let punctualityOptions = ["XX has excellent punctuality", "XX has good punctuality", "XX has poor punctuality"];
// Improvement Options
let improvementsOptions = ["XX should carry on as they have", "XX could make some improvements", "XX must improve"];

// Step 2 - Target the ID; objects to be used in the select below.

let dropDownConfig = [{
    id: "progressDropdown",
    categoryOptions: progressOptions
  },
  {
    id: "behaviourDropdown",
    categoryOptions: behaviourOptions
  },
  {
    id: "attendanceDropdown",
    categoryOptions: attendanceOptions
  },
  {
    id: "punctualityDropdown",
    categoryOptions: punctualityOptions
  },
  {
    id: "improvementsDropdown",
    categoryOptions: improvementsOptions
  },
]

// Step 3 - For Loop Passing the Values from progressOptions as option elements in HTML

function populateSelects(dropDownConfig) {
  for (let di = 0; di < dropDownConfig.length; di++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < dropDownConfig[di].categoryOptions.length; i++) {
      let opt = dropDownConfig[di].categoryOptions[i];

      let el = document.createElement("option");
      el.text = opt;
      el.value = opt;

      document.getElementById(dropDownConfig[di].id).add(el);
    }
  }
}
// Step 4 - Function which will print the selected value into the content HTML element
// Need helping turning this into a callback for the function above.
// I want this function to run but only when the select box is changed.
function printSelection(e) {

  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML+=  e.value+' ';
}

populateSelects(dropDownConfig);
```

```html
<body>
  <select id="progressDropdown" onchange="printSelection(this)">
    <option>Progress Dropdown</option>
  </select>
  <select id="behaviourDropdown" onchange="printSelection(this)">
    <option>Behaviour Dropdown</option>
  </select>
  <select id="attendanceDropdown" onchange="printSelection(this)">
    <option>Attendance Dropdown</option>
  </select>
  <select id="punctualityDropdown" onchange="printSelection(this)">
    <option>Punctuality Dropdown</option>
  </select>
  <select id="improvementsDropdown" onchange="printSelection(this)">
    <option>Improvements Dropdown</option>
  </select>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick response and such a clever solution. I've just given it a go and it works perfectly, and I'm going to study your code to make sure I understand exactly what is happening in each part (though I think I get it).

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in which you can pass the dropdown element and extract its value.

```
function printSelected(element){
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = element.value;
}
```

And change your HTML as :

```
<select id="progressDropdown" onchange="printSelected(this)">
        <option>Progress Dropdown</option>
    </select>
```

You can use this function with all other dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks for such a clever solution. I've tried another solution given by another user but I've learned a lot from yours too. Thanks!